# How to check output on mobile instead of Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to connect mobile device to eclipse to use it  as a emulator.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html i refer this link but not able to connect 
please suggest any other setting remains

Comment: what device are you trying to connect?

Comment: i am using LGP350 mobile

Comment: What errors or problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

I have connected my htc device instead of emulator to run my application.
I did the following steps

1.download htc sync software
2.install it to the system.
3.when connected,it shows one dialog then choose htc sync.
3.finally ,choose run as configuration and change automatic to manual.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices dont even require htc sync. For eg the old G1 does not require htc sync. But I guess newer phones would require it.

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your USB cable can be detected in your system. If detected then install proper driver as mentioned in the following link. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html. If you are using Mac machine then no need of installing driver. connect the device right click the project , run-as select the target device. make sure that target device of your project shoul be same or lower than that of the actual device. u will get the name of the device. select the device. and you application will run directly in mobile.

Thanks
Deepak